# Pipenv fails to install boto3 on remote server (Heroku)

Tags: django, heroku, boto3, pipenv

I deployed my django project successfully, then I wanted to use AWS S3 for serving static files. So I installed the required packages and everything worked locally. But now when I try `git push heroku master` it fails with the following traceback:

```
Writing objects: 100% (370/370), 5.85 MiB | 2.92 MiB/s, done.
Total 370 (delta 69), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.6.10
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: cp: cannot create regular file '/app/tmp/cache/.heroku/requirements.txt': No such file or directory
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.9
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
remote:        Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (acd4c8)…
remote:        An error occurred while installing boto3==1.12.31! Will try again.
remote:        Installing initially–failed dependencies…
remote:        Collecting boto3==1.12.31 
remote:          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2a/4f/3facbb42e8d07db1ef9b8cefb28dd1dbfcd52a8e32a0323d57f59b10e147/boto3-1.12.31-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        
remote:        THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM Pipfile.lock!. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
remote:            boto3==1.12.31 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2a/4f/3facbb42e8d07db1ef9b8cefb28dd1dbfcd52a8e32a0323d57f59b10e147/boto3-1.12.31-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=8bf7e3611d46e8214bf225169ac55de762d9d341514f81ebae885dd601138fcf (from -r /tmp/pipenv-sdy5o9v6-requirements/pipenv-k_8vold6-requirement.txt (line 1)):
remote:                Expected sha256 913fc7bbb9df147ed6fa0bd2b391469652ee8cad3e26ca2355e6ff774d9516fb
remote:                     Got        8bf7e3611d46e8214bf225169ac55de762d9d341514f81ebae885dd601138fcf
remote:        
remote:        You are using pip version 9.0.2, however version 20.0.2 is available.
remote:        You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to shielded-coast-69749.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/shielded-coast-69749.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/shielded-coast-69749.git'
```

Previously I had a similar issue trying to install psycopg2 locally, but after many attempts still haven't found anything but a workaround (installing psycopg2-binary instead). So here I feel a bit hopeless too. I tried `pipenv sync`, `pipenv update`, eventually I restarted with a new venv, but it didn't help. If I try to install boto3 via heroku's bash, it works. But it doesn't solve the problem since files are locked.

Comment: for  psycopg2 issue  post  the  error. but  psycopg2 isn't really required as  psycopg2-binary are same packages .But psycopg2 will compile the package  in ur  machine  for faster runtime.but as  u are trying  to  use  heroku it will have the same issue in  heroku that u are facing  in  local. so  try  to stick to psycopg2-binary or  use docker.

Comment: @LIONELVSV thanks, I mentioned psycopg2 because heroku installs it automatically if it's missing (ignoring psycopg2-binary) so there may be more dependencies compared to my local setup.

Comment: it will only  install packages mentioned  in pipfile as  long as u don't have requirements.txt file  check if  u have requirement.txt  or  psycopg2 present  if  it present remove  manually. uninstalling a  package from pipenv  doesn't remove a package from  pipenv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django-storages depends on  boto3 version of 1.4.4 and above but pipenv installs  1.12.31  which was released on  mar 28.So there might be cache  mismatch between heroku and pypi.org. so u can downgrade boto3 by manually installing boto3 by using  the  following command

`pipenv install "boto=1.4.4"`

I have specified 1.4.4 as it is the minimum version required by django-storages.But u can install any  version above 1.4.4.

Comment: When I tried to downgrade boto3, there was some error asking me if pypi is reachable and suggesting to run `pipenv lock --clear` (which didn't help). So started with a new venv once again, this time specifying boto3 version: `pipenv install boto3==1.11.*  and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: thats  because some other  package  is  using  higher version of boto3  it will say  which  package  try to remove the  package from  pipfile  and run pipenv  lock  cause  even if u  uninstall  an package  as  long  as it remain in  pipfile it will not remove the package.As  u have  mentioned  u were able to fix  the  issue try  to remember this  when u facing dependency issue in feature .